# How to handle global npm packages after periodic brew upgrade?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, homebrew

Updating `node` on OS X if `node` is set up with Homebrew basically appears to nuke my `npm -g` global packages.

For example my Vim's Syntastic usually runs `jshint` on js files, but once I update `node` this will usually just start failing silently.

I'm not really sure what I'm supposed to do about this. I'd like at the very least for there to be some kind of alert that says

> Here is the list of global npm packages you currently have installed, these will all be gone after I am done updating node.js!

Answer (score 0):

To fix this kind of problem, I use nvm(Node Version Manager), not brew's node.

```
brew uninstall node
brew install nvm
```

Add these line to .bashrc or .bash_profile

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

Install node using nvm

```
nvm install 0.10
nvm use 0.10
nvm alias default 0.10
```

You can see this result

```
$ node -v
v0.10.30

$ which node
/Users/yourid/.nvm/v0.10.30/bin/node
```